# Multi source BFS multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, breadth-first-search

I have a graph represented with an adjacency matrix `arr`. And a vector `source` for the multiple starting vertices.

My idea is to split the `source` vector into "equal" pieces depending on the number of threads(if it doesn't split equally I add the remaining on the last piece). And create threads that run this function. `bool used[]` is a global `array`

I am trying to get (I think its called) "liner"  scaling. I assume the number of starting vertices is at least equal to the number of threads.

If I use a mutex to synchronise the threads it is very inefficient.
And If I don't some vertices get traversed more then once.
Question is there a data structure that would let me remove the mutex?
or another way to implement this algorithm?

````
mutex m;
void msBFS(bool** arr, int n, vector<int> s, atomic<bool>* used) //s is a different
                                                   // piece of the original source 
{
    queue<int> que;
    for(auto i  = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        que.push(s[i]);
        used[s[i]] = true; 
    }
    while (!que.empty())
    {
        int curr = que.front();
        que.pop();
        cout << curr << " ";
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(m);
            if (arr[curr][i] == 1 && !used[i] && curr != i)
            {
                que.push(i);
                used[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: According to the C++ Standard, there is a _data race_ in your code, which means _undefined behavior_. Whether on some particular architecture, some particular implementation creates an assembly code that does not cause any problems — it's possible, but I wouldn't count on it unless I inspected that assembly and was very well familiar with the memory model of that architecture.

Comment: @Daniel Langr would a simple mutex in the body of the if fix that?

Comment: Yes, mutex may fix that, but will likely be very inefficient, if there will be only one mutex for the whole array (you need to protect reads of array elements as well). Much better would be to use atomic accesses to array elements. Unfortunately, since C++20, there is no `std::atomic_ref`, but you can create a dynamic array of `std::atomic<bool>` elements.

Comment: I'm joining @DanielLangr's proposal to use `std::atomic`. But watch out for other side effects in your algorithm. If that is only about changing this `bool` flag then it is fine. If you change other data (regardless atomic or not) then overall modification might be not atomic anymore.

Comment: @VladimirBerlev @DanielLangr you are both right, I made ```atomic<bool> used[ ]```, however, the logic doesn't seem to work. And a mutex around the ```if```  is correct but very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `atomic<bool>` I think you are almost there. The only piece missing is the atomic exchange operation. It allows you to read-modify-write as an atomic operation. For `bool` atomic type there is usually a piece of hardware that supports it.

```
void msBFS(bool** arr, int n, vector<int> s, atomic<bool>* used) //s is a different
                                                   // piece of the original source 
{
    //used[i] initialized to 'false' for all i
    queue<int> que;
    for(auto i  = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        que.push(s[i]);
        //we don't change used just yet!
    }
    while (!que.empty())
    {
        int curr = que.front();
        que.pop();
        bool alreadyUsed = used[curr].exchange(true);
        if(alreadyUsed) {
            continue; //some other thread already processing it
        }
        cout << curr << " ";
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (arr[curr][i] == 1 && !used[i] && curr != i) {
                que.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, there is one logical change: the `used[i]` is set to `true` when a thread starts processing the node, and not when it is added to the queue. 
At the first attempt to process a node, when `used[i]` is set to true, `alreadyUsed` will hold the previous value (`false`) indicating that noone else started processing the node earlier. At subsequent attempts to process the node, `alreadyUsed` will be already set to `true` and the processing will skip.

The above approach is not ideal: it is possible for a node to be added many times to a queue before it is processed. Depending on the shape of your graph it may or may not be a problem.

If this is a problem - I would suggest using a three-value `used` state: `not_visited`, `queued` and `processed`.

```
static constexpr int not_visited = 0;
static constexpr int queued = 1;
static constexpr int processed = 2;
```

Now, every time we try to push onto the `que`, and every time we try to process the node, we advance the state accordingly. These advancements need to be performed atomically, via `compare_exchange_strong` so that each change may happen exactly once.  The call to `compare_exchange_strong` returns `true` if it succeeded (i.e. the previously contained value actually matched the `expected` one)

```
void msBFS(bool** arr, int n, vector<int> s, atomic<int>* used) //s is a different
                                                   // piece of the original source 
{

    //used[i] initialized to '0' for all i
    queue<int> que;
    int empty = 0;
    for(auto i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        int expected = not_visited;
        //we check it even here, because one thread may be seriously lagging behind others which already entered the while loop
        if(used[s[i]].compare_exchange_strong(expected, queued)) {
            que.push(s[i]);
        }
    }
    while (!que.empty())
    {
        int curr = que.front();
        que.pop();
        int expected = queued;
        if(!used[curr].compare_exchange_strong(expected, processed)) {
            continue;
        }
        cout << curr << " ";
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (arr[curr][i] == 1 && curr != i) {
                int expected = not_visited;
                if(used[i].compare_exchange_strong(expected, queued)) {
                    que.push(i);
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check the performance. There are many atomic operations, but those are generally cheaper than a mutex. Internally, mutex also performs atomic operations similar to these, but in addition it may completely block a thread. The code I have shown never blocks (the thread is never put on a halt), all synchronization is done on the atomic variables only.

---

**Edit:** Some possible optimisations for second approach:

- I realized, that if the transition `not_visited->queued` is guaranteed to occur exactly once, the other transition does not even have to be performed, because the node is present exactly once in exactly one queue anyway. So, you may save up on few atomic operations and use `bool` again. Since it is rare, though, I don't think it will have that much of an impact.
- When iterating over the neighbors - there is an if statement: `if (arr[curr][i] == 1 && curr != i)` -- this does not check if the neighbor was visited or not. It is checked only later, through the atomic exchange. However, you may want to see if checking within that `if` anyway will help. If you find early that `used[i]` is already in a queue or processed, you skip over the branch, and over the no-longer-needed atomic compare-and-swap.
- If you want to squeeze every tick from your processor, consider using bitfields, instead of bools for your adjacency matrix and `used` array. I think the iteration over neighbors, and the conditions can be evaluated with bitwise operations, for 32 bits/neighbors at once. There is even `std::atomic<uint32_t>::fetch_or` to aid you with updating 32 `used` at once.

**Edit2:** Possible optimisation for first approach:

Each thread can hold its own `localUsed` array, which would be checked and set to `true` when pushing to the queue (similarly how you did in your original code). This would be local for the thread, so no atomics, mutexes etc. With this simple check you have a guarantee that a given node appears in a queue of each thread at most once. So, at most, a node will appear N times, where N is the number of threads.
I think this is a compromise worth considering between scalability and the memory footprint, and may perform better than the second approach.

Comment: Phenomenal answer in my opinion. Exactly what was needed and the 2nd approach is quite elegant. I did some testing on randomly generated graphs of around 40k-70k vertices with 2-4 threads. The first approach gives excellent scaling. Just as you said a lot of vertices are added to the queue(I need to think if this brakes the answer) which uses a lot of memory.  The 2nd' approach scaling is less good, however from what I see its due to the random nature of the graph (it depends on the staring vertices and the way I look for neighbours which is always from 0 to n). This is a universal solution.

Comment: @yoloexpectz Added a few pointers for possible optimizations if you are interested :)

Comment: @yoloexpectz Regarding the correctness of the first approach - no, multiple elements in the queue should not affect the answer. That's the job of `alreadyUsed` to ensure that each node gets through exactly once.